# Error on data-bind attribute in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, knockout.js

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='Script/v1.0.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();    
    }, this);
}
```

Activates knockout.js:

```html
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
          <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
          <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>

          <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
          <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>

          <p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>

        </div>
</form>
</body>
```

> data-bind is not working.
>
> error:databind is not a valid attribute

Comment: It is the simple and foremost example in **knockoutjs** . How you get error on this?

Comment: why i am getting this error.should i use html5. is it possible in visual studio 2008

Answer (score 0):

May Your problem is binding the ko.

**Try to bind your viewModel for a particular div id like below code.It may solve your prob**

**Html**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="test">
...
<div>
</form>
```

**Script:-**

```
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(), document.getElementById('form1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if you have selected the HTML5 tab above.
Then add the script files in your view: knockout-2.1.0.js, knockout-2.1.0.debug.js from your scripts folder.